# Send same data by setInterval for users

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I want to send monster damage the same for all users that connects to the game. The problem at the moment I believe that my code is in `io.on('connection', function (socket) {` and if there are two users joined at different times the damage will be send two times for both users and it will be different like `53, 24`. I need to achieve that no matter when player joins the game the damage should be sent only one time and it has to be the same for all players. Right now I'm sending it every 5 seconds from the server. What I'm thinking to do is storing timestamp with damage in database and send it to all users. Or maybe I can achieve that with the code that I have at the moment ?

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    setInterval(() => {
        monsterDamage = Math.floor(Math.random() * monsters[defeats.defeats].damageB) + monsters[defeats.defeats].damageA;

        User.findOne({username: username, ingame: true}).then((user) => {
            if(!user) {
                return console.log('User not found');
            }
                user.hp -= monsterDamage;
                if(user.hp < 0 || user.hp === 0) {
                    user.hp = 0;
                    user.ingame = false;
                    console.log('You LOST');
                }

                io.emit('monster-attack', {
                    damage: monsterDamage
                });
                console.log(monsterDamage);

                user.save();
        });

    }, 5000);

});
```

Keep in mind that this code is in `io.on('connection', function (socket) {`. So I believe if theres two players, two connections two damages has been sent or I'm wrong ?

Comment: That part of code is not included in your question.

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand Which part ?

Comment: `io.on('connection', function (socket) {`

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand Well I've added it but it won't help much

Comment: It helped a lot. You are setting an interval for any new connection. That's why two users get informed twice and if the third is added all 3 of them get 3  messages with different content.

Comment: Yeah I explained that at my question. So how to prevent this ? @RemisaYousefvand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a design problem. You have some users and they may connect to your server and you want to inform connected users in something happens. First take `setInterval` out of `io.on('connection'`.

In `io.on('connection'` keep track of users for example in an array (remember to remove them when the connection is closed). Now you have an updated list of all connected users inside your global array.

In `setInterval` part send message to members of that array.

**Code sample:**

```
const users = []

// io defined

setInterval(() => {
  // iterate users array and notify them of event
})

io.on('connection', (socket) {
  // update users array for example: users.push(socket)
})

io.on('disconnect', (socket) {
  // update users array. Remove disconnected user from array.
})
```

Comment: I have users array in io connection code block. But then again if I take my `setInterval` out of `io.on` how to emit monster damage ?

Comment: Why do you need an `emit`? notify users in `setInterval` although doing it with `emit` is also possible.

Comment: How can then I just send data in real time without socket to users ? hmm SetInterval is now in `Route` not in the `io.on`

Comment: What to use to notify users of the event ?

Comment: @zlotte: Keep a reference to user's socket in your global data structure (in my example the array) then use each user's socket to inform him.